# Google apps script form - e.response undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, gs-installable-triggers

I have set up a simple Google Form tied to a spreadsheet and added an installable trigger that calls onFormSubmit when a user submits the form.

Here's the onFormSubmit code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log("e: " + e);
  Logger.log("e.response: " + e.response);
  Logger.log("e.namedValues: " + e.namedValues);
}
```

Here's what's in the log:

```
[19-07-19 11:07:09:378 PDT] e: [object Object]
[19-07-19 11:07:09:378 PDT] e.response: undefined
[19-07-19 11:07:09:379 PDT] e.namedValues: [object Object]
```

Why is e.response undefined?

Looking through other posts seems to point to a possible apps script  bug, but I haven't found anything definitive and non of the workaround I've found work.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Just to double check - these are log entries from when the trigger runs, not manual runs correct?

Comment: @ross - yes, these log  entries are a result of the trigger running from a  my submitting the form.

Comment: [Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) for a Spreadsheet has no e.response.  [Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4) for a form has an e.response.

Comment: If your writing code in the code editor for the form then you'll have an e.response.  If you writing in the code editor for the spreadsheet they you won't have an e.response.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much Cooper. Seems like e.namedValues only works in scripts tied to sheets and e.response only works in scripts tied to forms.

Comment: Take a look at my links above and you can see for yourself what each of the event objects contain.